# How can I update IDAPython for IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, idapython

IDA Pro currently runs with IDAPython 1.0.

How can I update the IDAPython version?

Will IDA Pro also run with later versions of IDAPython?

Answer (score 3):

IDAPython is [open sourced](https://github.com/idapython/src). Using the IDA SDK you got with your IDA installation you can build IDAPython from source. You'll have to use the correct SDK, obviously.